# What's the official name of concept of input boxes with tags?

Tags: controls, web, input-fields, javascript

I'm looking for an implementation and the (official) name of this kind of control where it's a inputbox where we can add multiple tags into it.  By example, it is used in JIRA like this capture (and sites in stackexchange are good examples too, it's the control used to input tags):
[image: Screen capture of control used by JIRA.]

Some people call them SuperBox Select, but SuperBox sometimes refers to a lightbox (displaying pictures, etc).  So, the real name does not seem clear.

And if you have a tutorial to integrate this kind of control within a website (by a JavaSrcipt framework I think), it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery libraries that add support for this kind of input call it a tag input or token input and they are a form of auto-complete.

Mac OSX mail uses it for recipients in your address book:

[image]

For some examples / tutorials:
tag input (http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/) or 
token input (http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/, http://textextjs.com/manual/examples.html)

Comment: In the JQuery UI its just called an [auto complete input with multiple values](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple)

Comment: Yes, but this does not create the visual style of tags or tokens.

Answer (score 2):

[TextboxList](http://www.devthought.com/projects/mootools/textboxlist/) is one popular name.

Although there are only 11 or so [questions tagged textboxlist on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/textboxlist) there are no synonyms for it.

TextboxList is also the object used on Behance.net where this utility is used frequently for tags, skills, creative fields etc.