# What is the technical term or common name for this widget?

Tags: gui-design, names, dynamic-ui

What would you call the UI element that allows a user to add and remove elements from a collection as the favourite / ignored tags widget on the homepage of any stack exchange site does?

[image]

Comment: Well that's a combination of functional elements there, rather than one single component, but maybe this might help?: [What's the official name of concept of input boxes with tags?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/35167/whats-the-official-name-of-concept-of-input-boxes-with-tags)

Answer (score 4):

In both [MooTools](https://www.google.de/#q=TextboxList+mootools)' and [jQuery](https://www.google.de/#q=TextboxList+jquery)'s userspace, this is called 'TextboxList', so it is very reasonable to use that name.

Answer (score 3):

I would call it a list or tag builder.

Answer (score 2):

Textboxlist seems to be the most common name, although I find the following names a bit better, clearer:

- TagListBox
- LabelListBox

Answer (score 1):

I see it as 2 entities, the top one being the tag list, which the current tags and the bottom one being the Tag(input) box.